# Orbeon Form Builder, redirecting after save

Tags: orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

I`m using persistence API in form builder, but i can't redirecting orbeon form builder after pushing 'save' button. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at the [Buttons and Processes documentation](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Buttons-and-Processes). This allows you to create simple workflows when a button is pressed. So you could have a button which saves, then redirects to another page.